# GET changes the variable to false

Tags: c#, return

I'm trying to learn how to work in an AddIn. I know it's not that good idea to develop probrams in AddIn, but I want to do it.

I've made an User Control window that takes 2 parameters (width and height). These parameters will change the size of the user control window when a button is clicked.

The problem is that when I call the GET method to see if the button is clicked it always returns false.

```
    public int WindowWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return int.Parse(textBox_width.Text);
        }
        set
        {
            textBox_width.Text = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    public int WindowHeight
    {
        get
        {
            return int.Parse(textBox_height.Text);
        }
        set
        {
            textBox_height.Text = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    public bool ModifyIsClicked
    {
        get
        {
            return _ModifyIsClicked;
        }
        set
        {
            _ModifyIsClicked = value;
        }
    }

    private void button_modify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Width " + WindowWidth + " and Height " + WindowHeight);
        _ModifyIsClicked = true;
    }

    private bool _ModifyIsClicked;
```

This is the code that verifies if the button was clicked and changes the window size:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();

if (mainWindow.ModifyIsClicked == true)
{
    toolWin.Width = mainWindow.WindowWidth;
    toolWin.Height = mainWindow.WindowHeight;
    mainWindow.ModifyIsClicked = false;
}
```

I forgot to mention that the code above is in the "public void QueryStatus" from the Connect class.

Using debug I've seen how the variable _ModifyIsClicked changes to TRUE and the second it reaches "return _ModifyIsClicked;" it turns into FALSE.

When the variable becomes [True](http://postimg.org/image/6r4kj0moj/)

When the variable becomes [False](http://postimg.org/image/uc6gqnobd/)

Comment: When you initialize a new MainWindow form, _ModifyIsClicked value is always false.

Comment: I know. The idea is that the if statement must be accessed only when the button is clicked, only then the value of _ModifyIsClicked changes to false.

Comment: If that is the *exact* way and place you check `mainWindow.ModifyIsClicked` then it will never work. You need to actually run that code when the button is clicked so it happens.

Comment: I've tried like this, but doesn't solve the problem: `MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                    bool buttonclick = mainWindow.ModifyIsClicked;

                    if (buttonclick == true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've talked to someone and explained me the problem.

The main object in which I work with the text boxes and the button is created in the method "Exec". It's my fault because I didn't realized where the `MainWindows()` object was created. I tough that it was never created.

Every time I made an action like clicking the button I could see how my variable changed its value, but the default value of the variable for each object its "false". So when I was creating "the first object": `MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();` , actually I was creating a different object that was outside my Tool Window.

That's the reason that I was always getting "false" as result.

Answer (score 0):

```
     MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();

     private void button_modify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Width " + WindowWidth + " and Height " + WindowHeight);
        _ModifyIsClicked = true;     
        if (mainWindow.ModifyIsClicked == true)
        {
            toolWin.Width = mainWindow.WindowWidth;
            toolWin.Height = mainWindow.WindowHeight;
            mainWindow.ModifyIsClicked = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The "if" statement is in Connect.cs file, in the "public void QueryStatus" method. I've done this because for now I don't know an other way to modify the window dimensions. The "private EnvDTE.Window toolWin;" and "private EnvDTE80.Windows2 toolWins;" are initialized in the Connect class from the Connect.cs file. "toolWin" is the variable used for interacting with the window.

Comment: `button_modify_Click` is *in* `MainWindow` (or at least appears to be), so you need to get access to `toolWin` (and don't even need the `ModifyIsClicked`).